# Gamecenter Crashes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I got my project and want to start with a Game Center integration so i checked several GitHub - how they done it.

Thats what i did for now

1. Added Gamecenter to my Project in Capabilities Tab in my Target
2. Added `import GameKit`
3. Added `var player = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()` to my variables
4. Added

   ```
   var nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
       nc.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("authChanged"), name: GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName, object: nil)

           if player.authenticated == false {
           player.authenticateHandler = { (viewController, error) -> Void in

               if viewController != nil{
                   self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
           }

       }
   ```

   to My Code

But this crashes my App does i do anything wrong?

Here a Screenshot of the crash [image: screenshot] [big screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESqr9.png)

Comment: What line does it crash on and what do you have a stack trace?

Comment: here is a screenshot of xcode http://i.imgur.com/x1P0YVv.png?1 @BenTrengrove